# Matlab sequential file loop issues

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Just needing some help with some of my matlab code.

```
%import Sequential files

clc % clear window
clear %clear workspace

numfiles=4;

data=cell(1,numfiles);

for k = 2:numfiles
    myfilename=sprintf('J678501%d.mat',k);
    data{k}=importdata(myfilename);
end

for a= 1:3
    order_directory(a)=data(:,(a+1));
end


**for n = 56:59
   F=getfield((data{1,2}),sprintf('order_%d',n));
end**

wavelength=F(:,1);
intensity=F(:,2);
```

The asterisked area is where I need help with.

My files are listed in orders from order_56 to order_141 (i've just put 56:59 for the time being to ), however I'm missing a few orders (such as order_60 and order_100 - maybe others in other files.. it's not consistent) How can I get matlab to just skip a file if it's not there and go through to the next file?

Thanks
Caz

Comment: You can use `dir` to list all of the files in a particular directory, then simply loop over all of the possible names in this directory.  This way you won't risk trying to read in a file that doesn't exist.  You just read all of the files in the directory.

Comment: @rayryeng how would I go about doing this? I'm quite new to matlab

Comment: @CazV did my answer work? If so, mark it as accepted so that people know that you don't have this problem, and they can take a look at your new one.

Comment: @David How do I do that?

Comment: If it didn't work don't accept it! There's a tick mark on the left of the answer that you can use to mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't test this, but you can use `exist` to check whether a file exists. Then just keep track of which ones do exist in the `fileNumbers` vector, and use that to loop over.

```
fileNumbers=[];
for k = 2:numfiles
    myfilename=sprintf('J678501%d.mat',k);
    if exist(myfilename)
        fileNumbers=[fileNumbers k];
        data{k}=importdata(myfilename);
    end
end
```

and then when you use the data

```
for n=fileNumbers
    F=getfield((data{1,2}),sprintf('order_%d',n));
end
```

Comment: It didn't work but I think i've tried something else that might be better?

Comment: Did it give an error or just not work properly? I tried it with a simple example and it seemed to work.

Comment: The getfield line kept showing errors.. I could use it for one set of files but not another.. hence why I tried changing the code to make it easier?